# How to change color of paragraph each second with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a paragraph every second. I'm using the following function:

```
var ChangeColorGreen = function(){ $('#contact-title p').css('color', '#5fc091'); return true; }
    var ChangeColorBlack = function(){ $('#contact-title p').css('color', '#000'); return true; }

    setTimeout(function() {
      ChangeColorGreen();
      setInterval(function() {
        ChangeColorBlack();
      }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="contact-title">
  <p>Coming Soon</p>
</div>
```

But single-color changes paragraph once. No color changes again.

Comment: there isn't anything that is calling the alternative color. You are just calling the change to black function every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 classes `black` & `green` and toggle between them every second using `setInterval` function and JQuery **[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** function.

```js
setInterval(function() {
    $('#contact-title p').toggleClass('black green')
}, 1000);
```

```css
.black{
    color: #000;
}
.green{
    color: #5fc091;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact-title">
  <p>Coming Soon</p>
</div>
```

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set 2 intervals, each firing every 2 seconds but delay the 2nd one by 1 second.

```js
    setInterval(function() {
      ChangeColorGreen();
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        ChangeColorBlack();
      }, 2000);
    }, 1000);
```

Better still you can set 1 interval but use a flag, or some other way to determine which color should be next.

```js
var nextColor = "green";

setInterval(function() {
  if (nextColor == "green") {
    ChangeColorGreen();
    nextColor = "black";
  } else {
    ChangeColorBlack();
    nextColor = "green";
  }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique function, and create a flag to change it to one color or another:

```js
function changeColor(t) {
  document.querySelector('#contact-title > p').style.color = t ? '#000' : '#5fc091';
  setTimeout(function() {
    changeColor(!t);
  }, 2000);
}

changeColor(true);
```

```html
<div id="contact-title">
  <p>Coming Soon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a single function and a flag variable and have the following:

```
var isGreen = false;
function toggleColor(){
    if(isGreen){isGreen = false; ChangeColorBlack();}
    else{isGreen = true; ChangeColorGreen();}
}
```

and call it via a setInterval as such

```
setInterval(function() {
    toggleColor();
}, 2000);
```